# VSCode regular expression notation for numbered backreferences and other replacement pattern placeholders

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Does VSCode have support for [numbered backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)? I'm trying to do a find replace from the dialog but it matches the entire regex and replaces with a literal `\1`

[image: find replace dialog attempt at numbered backreference syntax]

```
# Regex
<tr><th align="right">target</th><td><pre>(.*)</pre></td></tr>
```

What is the regex engine that VSCode actually uses under the hood?

Comment: Use `$1`..........

Comment: wonderful, that's the secret then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode search and replace feature uses ECMAScript standard for the regex based search, and the replacement backreferences are also those that can be used in JavaScript.

To insert Group 1 value use `$1`.

However, to replace with the whole match, you may use both `$&` (as in JavaScript) and `$0` (as in PCRE).

And remember to use `$$` to insert a *single literal `$`* char.

Note that beginning with Visual Studio Code v.1.31.0 release, as a result of [moving to Electron 3.0](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68004), you may use all the cool features ECMAScript 2018 provides (like infinite-width lookbehinds).